# Loading Word2Vec binary model from S3 into Gensim fails

Tags: python, amazon-s3, gensim, serverless

I have persisted a Word2Vec model to a binary file. I am trying to load it into a serverless API adapted from this [blog](https://medium.com/@patrickmichelberger/how-to-deploy-a-serverless-machine-learning-microservice-with-aws-lambda-aws-api-gateway-and-d5b8cbead846) and using [this](https://ryan-cranfill.github.io/gensim-aws-lambda/) as a basis.

This works fine locally:

```
self.model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./models/models.bin', binary=True)
```

but when calling the file from S3 it errors with:

> 'IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '46659 100\n,|PUNCT
>   \xec>\xd8>\xaf\xa8\x95'

```
def load_model(key):
response = S3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=key)
model_str = response['Body'].read()

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_str, binary=True)
return model
```

Answer (score 7):

A cleaner and faster way is to load the model directly from S3 through `smart_open` which is used by `gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load()` as well as `gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()`.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'abc'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'abc'
url = 's3://' + AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID + ":" + AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY + "@bucket/file.model"
wv = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load(url)
```

See examples on `smart_open` in the README: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open

Answer (score 1):

I think it's cleaner to download the file to disk, then read it from python rather than trying to load that file directly into memory with `get_object()`. If can always remove the downloaded file if disk space is a concern.

This works perfectly for me:

```
session = boto3.Session()
s3 = session.resource('s3')
destination_file = 'model.bin.gz'
s3.meta.client.download_file(bucket_name, object_name, destination_file)
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(destination_file, binary=True)
```